# directory listing to xml - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects - How To Handle?

Tags: python, xml

Using part of a script I found on here to run through the directories on a Windows PC to produce an XML file. However I am running into the above error and I am not sure how to handle the error. I have added a try/except in however it still crashes out. This works perfectly if i set the directory to be my Current Working Directory by replacing the "DirTree3("C:/") " with "DirTree3((os.getcwd())"

```
def DirTree3(path):
    try:
        result = '<dir>%s\n' % xml_quoteattr(os.path.basename(path))
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
            if os.path.isdir(itempath):
                result += '\n'.join('  ' + line for line in
                                    DirTree3(os.path.join(path, item)).split('\n'))
            elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
                result += '  <file> %s </file>\n' % xml_quoteattr(item)
        result += '</dir> \n'
        return result
    except Exception:
        pass


print '<DirectoryListing>\n' + DirTree3("C:/") + '\n</DirectoryListing>'
```

As a side note, this script will be run on a system without admin privileges so running as admin is not an option

Comment: which line of code complain the error?

Comment: try/exception would not help, since your function return NoneType once it has exception

Comment: It complains on the last line; the one that calls the DirTree3 function. This works perfectly if i set the directory to be my Current Working Directory by replacing the "DirTree3("C:/") " with "DirTree3((os.getcwd())"

Comment: All that means is that doesn't encounter the same error it does when you start at `"C:/"`.

Comment: try to change c:/ to c:\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments below about getting and wanting to ignore any path access errors, I modified the code in my answer below to do that as best it can. Note that it will still terminate if some other type of exception occurs.

```
def DirTree3(path):
    try:
        result = '<dir>%s\n' % xml_quoteattr(os.path.basename(path))
        try:
            items = os.listdir(path)
        except WindowsError as exc:
            return '<error> {} </error>'.format(xml_quoteattr(str(exc)))

        for item in items:
            itempath = os.path.join(path, item)
            if os.path.isdir(itempath):
                result += '\n'.join('  ' + line for line in
                                    DirTree3(os.path.join(path, item)).split('\n'))
            elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
                result += '  <file> %s </file>\n' % xml_quoteattr(item)
        result += '</dir> \n'
        return result
    except Exception as exc:
        print('exception occurred: {}'.format(exc))
        raise

print '<DirectoryListing>\n' + DirTree3("C:/") + '\n</DirectoryListing>'
```

Comment: This does look like an access issue as this is the error received: exception occurred: [Error 5] Access is denied: '/$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18/*.*'.

Comment: Well, now you know the problem. How do you want to handle it?—we can't read your mind.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve the same outcome without running into permission issues? I have another piece of code which Hashes every file on the system and utilizes "os.walk". This does not have the same permission issues. Is it purely down to the "os.isdir" which has permission requirements?

Comment: So this other piece of code displays what's in the same directory that this code has a problem with, or does it just skip/ignore it?

Comment: Ignore this comment. Just noticed that it does not actually hash the same file as above, the Try/Except skips over it. However, i cant get this script to skip over errors as well

Comment: The code you added starts from `"C:/Windows/"` not `"C:/"`.

Comment: There was the same issue. I have removed the code above to save confusion. The issue remaining is how to skip over the files that it cannot process such as the "Recycle.Bin" files above?